# Polymer Service Worker Precache

Tags: spring, polymer, service-worker

I have a Spring Boot Application serving a Polymer starter kit from it's static folder. The UI-Application is served trough a Zuul proxy which handles Oauth2 Single Sign On. As soon as the user is authenticated, a cookie with JSESSIONID is set.

When I want to logout from the UI, I do a POST request to the /logout endpoint of Zuul, so the session gets destroyed. Upon successful logout, I reload the page via `location.reload()` which will redirect me to the login view, as the Singe Sign On client of Zuul will detect a not present session.

The above works fine until the service-worker kicks in. On `location.reload()` the service worker is going to serve all the cached pages, which than try to execute some request against my API (only authenticated users can access). The result is a 401 response, which is handled in an error handler that performs a logout, thus leading to an infinite loop.

The question now is, how can I avoid that the service-worker is serving my request after a post to /logout?

I don't have control over the JSESSIONID cookie, as it is set with HTTP-Only.

What I have tried so far:
Instead  of `location.reaload` I do `location.replace(location.origin + "/logout")` and add a `navigateFallbackWhitelist` to: `"^(?!.*\.html$|\/uaa\/|\/utr\/|\/logout\/).*"` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.reload(true)` does the trick.